# A problem related to infinitely often events

Tags: probability-theory

If the sets $A_n$ are independent and $P(A_n) < 1 \forall n$, then $P[A_n i.o.] = 1$ if $P(\cup_n A_n) =1$. 
I have a proof of this using the Borel Cantelli lemma. But the conditions (for example, divergence) is not necessary to prove it. 
Hence, can we have any other way to solve the problem. I tried to solve but I need to prove $P(\cup _{k=n} A_k) = 1 \forall n$. Stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

Since

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( \bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k \right) $$

it suffices to show

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( \left( \bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k \right)^c \right) = 0. \tag{1}$$

Since the sets $A_k$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$, are independent, we find that

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{P} \left( \left( \bigcup_{k=n}^{n+m} A_k \right)^c \right)&= \mathbb{P} \left( \bigcap_{k=n}^{n+m} A_k^c \right) = \prod_{k=n}^{n+m} \mathbb{P}(A_k^c) = \prod_{k=n}^{n+m} (1-\mathbb{P}(A_k)). \tag{2}\end{align*}$$

for any $m \geq 1$. We claim that there exist infinitely many $k$ such that $\mathbb{P}(A_k)>0$. Indeed: For any $k_1,\ldots,k_n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \left( \bigcup_{j=1}^n A_{k_j} \right)^c \right) = \prod_{j=1}^n (1-\mathbb{P}(A_{k_j}))>0$$ since, by assumption, $\mathbb{P}(A_{k_j})<1$. This shows that we cannot cover the probability space by finitely many sets.

Now letting $m \to \infty$ in $(2)$ proves $(1)$.